# How to keep only source files in project folder in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

When I create a new project in Visual Studio, after a session of working, the folder of the project is always filled with "junk" such as the `ipch` (precompiled header) folder, the `debug` folders, sql database files that I never made...

In short, is it possible to just keep the source files inside the folder of the project, and either

- automatically delete every other junk files after closing VS, or
- choose a different temporary folder for those junk to go in?

Answer (score 0):

You can delete ipch, Release, Debug, x64 directories and also *.suo and *.sdf files.  That will cause the compiler to re-create those files on the next run and maybe it needs some extra time to do so.

Plus, the *.suo files keep track of your open files, cursor positions in them, etc.  You return to a clean slate in VS if you delete them, but you don't loose any source code.

Comment: I know all that, what I want is doing all those thing automatically

Answer (score 0):

You can use the post-build event and delete the files using standard dos commands, or you can run a powershell script for example in the post build event. As for when you close visual studio, I don't think you can do this, you would need some sort of event  and a third party script or application.